# How to find objects based on index of Integer array?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I have an Integer array as

```
Integer[] myArray= {1,3};
```

I have another List of objects `MyDept` which has the properties `id` and `name`.

I want to get those objects of `MyDept` whose ids matches with the values of `myArray`.

If the objects in the list are

```
Objfirst(1,"Training"), Objsecond(2,"Legal"), Objthird(3,"Media")
```

then I want `Objfirst` and `Objthird`.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in two steps as :

```
List<MyDept> myDepts = new ArrayList<>(); // initialised arraylist of your objects

// collect the objects into a Map based on their 'id's
Map<Integer, MyDept> myDeptMap = myDepts.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(MyDept::getId, Function.identity()));

// iterate over the input array of 'id's and fetch the corresponding object to store in list
List<MyDept> myDeptList = Arrays.stream(myArray)
        .map(myDeptMap::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

with a minimal object as :

```
class MyDept{
    int id;
    String name;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: This is passing the index to `myDeptMap.get`, correct? I think you should pass the element at that index instead, i.e. I wouldn't use a range. Instead, I would just stream the array.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yes makes sense, updated. thanks